why does "console.warn" can effect the render result?
I tried to use flip animation loading effect when I click sumbmit button, but somehow this loading animation stuck when the loading change to false.
enter code hereexport const useFlipAnimate = (loading: boolean) => {
const degree = useSharedValue(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
        degree.value = withRepeat(
            withSequence(
                withTiming(90, { duration: 800, easing: Easing.linear }),
                withTiming(0, {
                    duration: 800,
                    easing: Easing.linear,
                }),
            ),
            -1,
        );
    } else {
        // console.warn("???"); // if I remove this line, the animation will not back to 0 degree.
        degree.value = 0;
    }
}, [loading]);

return useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ rotateY: `${degree.value}deg` }],
}));

};
